# ¿Cómo comparar una contraseña con las anteriores?

Tags: java

Necesito crear un método para cambiar contraseñas que devuelve un true/false dependiendo de si la nueva contraseña que recibe es distinta a las 4 anteriores. Lo máximo que puedo recorrer es hasta la anterior contraseña, intente lo siguiente pero solamente estaría trabajando con dos strings, el nuevo y el anterior. Desde ya Gracias!

```
public boolean cambiarContrasenia (String nuevaContraseña) {
    boolean contraseniaDistinta = false;
    String historialContrasenias = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        historialContrasenias = getContrasenia();
        if (nuevaContraseña != historialContrasenias) {
            contraseniaDistinta = true;
        }
        historialContrasenias = "";
    }
    
    if (contraseniaDistinta == true) {
        setContrasenia(nuevaContraseña);
    }
    
    return contraseniaDistinta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Código con correciones.

```
public boolean cambiarContrasenia(String nuevaContraseña) {
    
        // debe ser un arreglo de cadenas
        String[] historialContraseñas = new String[] {
            "123",
            "456",
            "abc",
            "xyz"
        };
    
        for (int i = 0; i < historialContraseñas.length; i++) {
            // comparar cadenas usando la función equals()
            // si la nuevaContraseña es igual a una contraseña antigua
            // retornar falso 
            if (nuevaContraseña.equals(historialContraseñas[i])) {
                return false;
            }
    
        }
        // si luego de comparar todas las contraseñas ninguna es igual
        // retornar verdadero
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo muchísimo mas fácil gracias a la función contains de List

Esta te comprueba si ya existe cierto objeto en una lista, usa el método equals , al ser una String el equals ya está implementado y no tienes que hacer nada

`public boolean cambiarContrasenia(String nuevaContrasena) {
return Arrays.asList("pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4").contains(nuevaContrasena);
}`